# JSoup, how to return data from a dynamic <a href> tag

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup

Very new to JSoup, trying to retrieve a changeable value that is stored within an  tag, specifically from the following [website](https://www.whoismytd.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&form-input=Kildare%20Street%2C%20Dublin%2C%20Ireland) and  html.
[Snapshot of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Wib.png)

the results after "consitituency/" are changeable and dependent on the input of the user. I am able to retrieve the h2 tags themselves but not the information within. At the moment the best return I can get is just tags using the method below

The desired return would be something that I can substring down into

> Dublin Bay South

The actual return is

> <well.col-md-4.h2></well.col-md-4.h2>

```
        private String jSoupTDRequest(String aLine1, String aLine3) throws IOException {
        String constit = "";
        String h2 = "h2";
     String url = "https://www.whoismytd.com/search?utf8=✓&form-input="+aLine1+"%2C+"+aLine3+"+Ireland";
        //Switch to try catch if time
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .timeout(6000).get();

        //Scrape elements from relevant section

        Elements body = doc.select("well.col-md-4.h2");
        Element e = new Element("well.col-md-4.h2");
        constit = e.toString();
        

        return constit;
```

I am extremely new to JSoup and scraping in general. Would appreciate any input from someone who knows what they're doing or any alternate ways to try and get the desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your scraping elements from relevant section code as follows:

- Select the very first `<div class="well">` element first.

  ```
  Element tdsDiv = doc.select("div.well").first();
  ```
- Select the very first `<a>` link element next. This link points to the constituency.

  ```
  Element constLink = tdsDiv.select("a").first();
  ```
- Get the constituency name by grabbing this link's text content.

  ```
  constit = constLink.text();
  ```

Comment: Dude, thank you. This works perfectly. Basically, what I needed to do was scrape down form the top and isolate the text part of the link?

Comment: @BadHombe Yes, and luckily all the elements that you needed to traverse through were the very first ones in their set of elements. If they were not, the selectors would have been more complex and/or we would have had to loop through them.

Comment: Haha, unfortunately I'm trying to figure out how to scrape the councillor result as well. Had hoped it would be as easy as switching .first with .last but that would have been too easy

Comment: @BadHombe Go through this beginner-friendly [CSS Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/) tutorial and give it a try. You can always post another question if you feel stuck, we'll be happy to help here.

Comment: @ Ravi K Thapliyal Thanks again man, will try to work out the second one myself using the link. If I can't get it I might leave a comment here tomorrow begging for help if that's ok?

Comment: Ah, Dude, I got it. Thank you so much. The tutorial you linked and your explanations could not have been anymore helpful. Just had to switch Element tdsDiv = doc.select("div.well").first(); with Element tdsDiv = doc.select("div.well").last(); to isolate the last piece. Thank you so much, assuming you're Indian good luck against the English in the rest of the test

Comment: @BadHombe Thank you for your kind words and best wishes ahead!

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

@DisplayName("JSoup, how to return data from a dynamic <a href> tag")
class JsoupQuestionTest {
    private static final String URL = "https://www.whoismytd.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&form-input=Kildare%20Street%2C%20Dublin%2C%20Ireland";
    @Test
    void findSomeText() throws IOException {
        String expected = "Dublin Bay South";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
        String actual = document.getElementsByAttributeValue("href", "/constituency/dublin-bay-south").text();
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual);

    }
}
```